# JSTL get serial number in a table

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I am using JSTL for each loop for iteration over a list & display that data in a table.

I would like to know how to display the serial number in that table.

```
<c:forEach items="${item.getApps()}" var="app">
<tr><td>....</td>             //need to display serial number here
<td><c:out value="${app.getApp()}"></c:out></td>
</tr></c:forEach>
```

TIA.

Comment: simply use app variable to do it. If your serial number is sr_no do {app.sr_no}

Comment: Do you have any serialNumber field or trying to show the index of the current record.

Comment: app variable is an object, item.getApps() will give me a list of app objects & it need to display that data into a table with serial Number as a column/index of that table.

Comment: @newuser: No i don't have serialNumber as a field on bjest I am using it only to render view as an index to a row

Comment: I already answered this question try it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **varStatus** attribute of that tag which keep track of loop status

```
<c:forEach items="${item.getApps()}" var="app" varStatus="counter">
<tr><td> ${counter.count}"</td>             //need to display serial number here
<td><c:out value="${app.getApp()}"></c:out></td>
</tr></c:forEach>
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Using [varStatus property](http://www.bmchild.com/2012/03/jstl-cforeach-varstatus-properties.html)

```
<c:forEach items="${item.getApps()}" var="app" varStatus="loop">
<tr><td>${loop.index}</td>             //need to display serial number here
<td><c:out value="${app.getApp()}"></c:out></td>
</tr></c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                  This should be work definitly
       <c:forEach items="${item.getApps()}" var="app" varStatus="counter">
       <tr><td> ${counter.index+1}"</td>             
       <td><c:out value="${app.getApp()}"></c:out></td>
       </tr>
       </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.